# Simple PHP issue

Tags: php, ternary-operator, conditional-statements

I'm new to shorthand conditional statements and I can't for the life of me work out how to do it, here's the simple code I have:

```
<?php

    function evolve_nav($vals) {

       echo '<'.$vals['type'] !== '' ? ''.$vals['type'].'' : 'darn''>';

    }

?>
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't return anything and results in an error?

Comment: -1, you didn't really say what you need in the question at all...just posted some code and said it doesn't work.

Comment: @Cyclone - Should I edit it to state the obvious that I want it to work?

Comment: no, but you could try to explain what "want it to work" actually means.

Comment: IMHO a good example of how not to use ternary operators - it makes the whole thing completely unreadable - which is why you've got the problem (order of evaluation - fixed with brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `''.$vals['type'].''` is superfluous, make it `$vals['type']`
- `'darn''>'` those are two string literals without any operator (or anything) between them -> syntax error.

In this case I'd rather not use string concatenation (i.e. using the dot-operator like `'xyz' . $a` ) but "pass" multiple parameters to echo.

```
echo
  '<',
  ''!==$vals['type'] ? $vals['type'] : 'darn',
  '>';
```

or using printf

```
printf('<%s>', ''!==$vals['type'] ? $vals['type'] : 'darn');
```

Comment: You say it's superfluous, which it is, but then go on to use it in your example?

Answer (score 5):

You just forgot some brackets:

```
function evolve_nav($vals) {
    echo '<'.(!empty($vals['type']) ? $vals['type'] : 'darn').'>';
}
evolve_nav(array('type' => 'foobar'));
evolve_nav(array('not' => 'showing'));
```

Comment: I just tested the above code (again) and I get the output `<foobar><damn>`, which is as expected. As you did not put in the function call in your pastebin, I'm unsure, if you have any errors there.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<' . ($vals['type'] !== '' ? $vals['type'] : 'darn') .'>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$descriptiveVariableName = $vals['type']!=='' ? $vals['type'] : 'darn';

// View code
echo "<$descriptiveVariableName>";
```

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? This is much more readable and addresses the OPs question about correct syntax. I'm upvoting back again :-)

Comment: @Chris Very kind of you. :) Yeah well there are many coders who have their own personal rules and if they believe somebody is breaking one they will downvote. :) I'm more curious as to why Lance went through everybody's posts and changed the word to "damn" to "darn". =D